# AngularJS Filter applied to an ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to make a filter on my `ng-repeat` list.
I have a list of services that gets returned in my return object.
Each of these services has a `StaffID` assigned to it.

I am trying to create a filter to `ng-repeat` the `services` filtered by the `StaffID`, but it's not working. I don't know how to syntax it correctly.
I want to do it strictly in HTML.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="service in vm.session.staffServices orderBy:'StaffID[0]'"ng-show="staff.AttendanceStatusID == '18'" class="form-group">
  <span>Services Provided:</span>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox">   {{service.ServiceName}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

the hierarchy in my object is like this:

```
Object => staffServices Array[4]=> [0] {ServiceID: 33, ServiceName: "Wilson", StaffID: 123} [1] {ServiceID: 44, ServiceName: "Tutoring", StaffID: 456}
```

I have two different teachers. so for each service from my `ng-repeat` I want to associate his `service`.

Using my filter by manipulations I was able to either display both services to each teacher, or NONE at all.

And No, I don't want to put a filter that will take `StaffID: '123'`. I have many teachers, and this particular session has only two.

Thank you

Comment: Why you are trying `orderBy:'StaffID[0]'`, it should try like this:  `ng-repeat="service in vm.session.staffServices | orderBy: StaffID"`

Comment: I have an ng-repeat on the staff in another div above. what i want is to associate the service of a provider to the provider. So I was just trying to play with the code to see if I can select the first provider and it will display his services.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that will help those that need to filter a list when the array of this list is on the Client side.

[AngularJS filter filter - Filtering and Sorting a List](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/filtering-and-sorting-a-list.html)

And here is my remade options list that is filtered by the StaffID

```
   <select ng-model="staff.ServiceID" ng-options="service.ServiceID as service.ServiceName for service in vm.session.staffServices | filter: { StaffID: staff.StaffID }">
        <option value="">-- Select Service --</option>
   </select>
```

Note how the filter was written.

And read the info in the link too. it will help.